# changing global slice in a function

Tags: function, pointers, go, slice

I've never worked with C/C++, so I'm a bit stuck with pointers in go. The problem is: I have a `map[string][]InteractiveItems` for each "room" and I wanna change slice of it in a function. Here it is:

```
func (r *room) getItem(arg string) InteractiveItem {
for i, val := range r.interactiveItems {
    for _, item := range val {
        if item.getName() == arg {
            var idxToDelete int
            for idx := range val {
                if val[idx].getName() == arg {
                    idxToDelete = idx
                    break
                }
                if len(val) == 0 {
                    delete(r.interactiveItems, i)
                }
            }
            val = append(val[:idxToDelete], val[idxToDelete+1:]...)
            return item
        }
    }
}
return nil
```

Obviously, `val` is changing inside the function, but room's map is not. How should I deal with pointers to delete the element of a slice?

Comment: Set the result of append to the slice you want to change inside the map ie. `r.interactiveItems[i] = append(val[:idxToDelete], val[idxToDelete+1:]...)`.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks! Write an answer, I'll mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because everything in Go is passed by value.

What this means for your case is that when you are iterating over the map, on each iteration the `val` variable is assigned a *copy* of the corresponding slice value. So re-slicing the `val` value inside the loop has no effect on the original slice inside the map, since one is a copy of, not a reference to, the other.

To change the slice that's inside the map you can re-assign the result of the `append` operation to the corresponding map key.

```
r.interactiveItems[i] = append(val[:idxToDelete], val[idxToDelete+1:]...)
```

Keep in mind that when a slice is copied it does not copy the data that the slice points to, it copies only the slice's "descriptor".